# How to call a Model Method from an HTML form input value

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a simple HTML form for filtering/ordering the data on the page. This uses a `GET` request to the view which returns the data from the back-end in the manner which was requested. What I want to do is use a Model Method, instead of an attribute, as the form's input value.

**Current example which passes Model attribute as input value** (current_score is a Model attribute):

```
<input class="form-check-input"
       id="Radios4"
       name="ordering"
       type="radio"
       value="-current_score">
<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios4">Scores: High-to-Low</label>
```

The problem with this is that `current_score` returns the quantity of correct questions while I want the user's percentage score on the test.

**Which is calculated using this Model Method**:

```
@property
def get_percent_correct(self):
    dividend = float(self.current_score)
    divisor = len(self._question_ids())
    if divisor < 1:
        return 0  # prevent divide by zero error
    if dividend > divisor:
        return 100
    correct = int(round((dividend / divisor) * 100))
    if correct >= 1:
        return correct
    else:
        return 0
```

So my question is, how can I use the Model Method as the input value in the form?

**Such as**:

```
<input class="form-check-input"
       id="Radios4"
       name="ordering"
       type="radio"
       value="get_percent_correct">
<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios4">Scores: High-to-Low</label>
```

The only options Django gives are Model attributes:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'get_percent_correct' into field. Choices are: complete, current_score, end, id, incorrect_questions, question_list, question_order, quiz, quiz_id, start, user, user_answers, user_id

Answer (score 0):

Since Django wants a Model attribute I decided to give it what it is asking for. I added a Model attribute named `percent_correct` which looks like this:

```
percent_correct = models.IntegerField(null=True, verbose_name=_("Percent Correct"))
```

Then I did an override of the Model `save` method to use the Model Method as a way to fill in this field during save:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.percent_correct = self.get_percent_correct
    super(Sitting, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now I can just call the newly created attribute/field as the value in the form:

```
<input class="form-check-input"
       id="Radios4"
       name="ordering"
       type="radio"
       value="percent_correct">
<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios4">Scores: High-to-Low</label>
```

If anyone else has other ways this could be handled I would love to know!